# Getting error while trying to run script on Webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to learn Selenium Webdriver.
I have downloaded eclipse and Webdriver dependency on my laptop.
I m trying to create script on selenium and during Running script i am getting below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\Admin\workspace\newproject\<Path to your WebDriver>
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:37)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:277)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:238)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
    at newpackage.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:11)
```

Comment: Post your script and your selenium configuration file.

Comment: Did you install Firefox and geckodriver? please share versions also along with code snippet

Comment: I have installed firefox